# How do I set up GWT Super Dev Mode with the new (tbroyer) maven-gwt-plugin on WildFly?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jboss, wildfly

With the [new maven-gwt-plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin) (which [officially](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/) replaces the legacy mojo one), I can run GWT Super Dev Mode as such:

```
mvn gwt:codeserver
```

How I do get my backend to run with WildFly (it uses JAX-RS and other JavaEE technologies)?

Comment: 1) how did you do it with the MojoHaus plugin? 2) maybe have a look at the wildfly-maven-plugin and wildfly:run/wildfly:start?

Comment: It needs to start as one process (so it can be killed as one, so it can be debugged as one, etc), so 2) isn't an option. For 1) I've seen people use a launcher, so I am trying that now too.

Answer (score 1):

**Use EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher**

- Add the `errai-cdi-jboss` dependency which includes a launcher for WildFly
- but also exclude the `apache-jsp` dependency from `gwt-dev` to avoid an error.

The parent `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <!-- Contains a ServletContainerInitializer that breaks the EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher during GWT Super Dev Mode -->
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <!-- Only used for EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher during GWT Super Dev Mode -->
  <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
  <artifactId>errai-cdi-jboss</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

- configure the WildFly launcher `EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher` from `errai-cdi-jboss` in the maven-gwt-plugin
- Configure the `errai.jboss.home` system property for the spawned process, so the launcher can start up WildFly.
- Configure the `warDir` to the exploded directory, so that the backend war is also loaded (so your REST/RPC calls coming from the GWT client actually have someone answering them on the backend).

That section in the parent `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <devmodeArgs>
          <!-- GWT Super Dev Mode: Replace default backend by WildFly -->
          <arg>-server</arg>
          <arg>org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher</arg>
          <arg>-startupUrl</arg>
          <arg>gwtui/gwtui.html</arg>
        </devmodeArgs>
        <!-- GWT Super Dev Mode: deploy backend correctly -->
        <warDir>optashift-employee-rostering-webapp/target/optashift-employee-rostering-webapp-${project.version}</warDir>
        <systemProperties>
          <!-- GWT Super Dev Mode: which WildFly to use -->
          <errai.jboss.home>${wildfly.home}</errai.jboss.home>
        </systemProperties>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

then run

```
mvn gwt:devmode
```

**IMPORTANT**: this doesn't work entirely because the backend isn't the actual wildfly war but only the gwt ui war...

Comment: @thomas-broyer The WildFly server starts up at port `9990`, devmode at port `9876`, but my REST requests from my GWT UI fail because the devmode server at `9876` ignores them. Any idea how I can get them to forward to `9990`? I am not using GWT-RPC.

Comment: Make them relative to `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` or `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()`?

Comment: Fixed with `warDir`, now everything runs to the wildfly port.